# Click Once Silent Updating Check For Application Updates Always Checked

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have implemented a silent updater into my WPF app to check for updates and silently install them in the background.

I've **unchecked** (Project Properties -> Publish -> Updates... -> "The application should check for updates") but when publishing it re-checks itself every time!

When I use `CheckForUpdate(false)` my app never updates silently, however it is setting the "UpdateAvailable" flag to true so on next launch I see the "Apply updates or skip" prompt.

When I use `CheckForUpdateAsync()` my app does update silently, and everything is almost fine. I say almost because after launching, the app is freezing. Presumably because it's checking for updates due to (Project Properties -> Publish -> Updates... -> "The application should check for updates after application starts")

Why is this rechecking itself and how can I disable it?

**[Update]**

Just running some tests I removed my call to `CheckForUpdateAsync()` and unchecked Project Properties -> Publish -> Updates... -> "The application should check for updates after application starts"). So absolutely no updating should be going on? After checking with Fiddler a call is still made to check for updates, how can this be?

Comment: Have you done any kind of Fiddler debugging on the client to verify that the network request is being made to check for updates?

Comment: Just checked, and yes Fiddler shows the app is checking for updates due to this magical self checking checkbox!

Comment: Then it sounds like we need to know more about the specifics of your background updater before an intelligent answer can be provided.  When working with WPF/ClickOnce ... depending on how you are building the update, via Publish, or manually with ,msbuild/MAGE... there may be options to look at there.

Comment: I am building updates via publish to an FTP location, I utilised Ivan's code shown here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/489763/Silently-updatable-single-instance-WPF-ClickOnce-a

Comment: I'm seeing this also. Did you figure out why this happens?

Comment: @John I never did find out what was happening with this, looks like you got closer to finding a solution that I ever did!

Answer (score 1):

As to the original question, I have discovered that when I update with the "Publish Now" button in the publication settings page of the application, the "The application should check for updates" setting is not set as it is when using "Publish" from the project context menu.

I'm using VS2013 and although that's probably a bug, there's this workaround.